# What can be the problems or danger of running a motor slower by simply lowering the dc voltage supplied to it?

Tags: voltage, motor, dc-motor

Any suggests explaining the consequences of slower a motor by lowering the DC voltage ?

Comment: What is your motor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's heavily loaded, it may bog down and stall, whereas running at the original higher voltage, it would run faster and ride through a heavy or uneven load.

When stalled, it will draw a high current and dissipate all that power as heat, not motion, and possibly burn out.

If it's lightly loaded, so you don't allow it to slow or stall under load, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a DC motor with a commutator, the motor should run fine and develop full torque at lower speeds. The torque vs speed characteristics will vary depending on the design: series, compound, shunt, or permanent magnet / separately supplied field. The main concern would be cooling. At full speed, the motor has some ability to move air in, through, or over itself for cooling. As the speed is reduced, that ability is reduced.

The operation of a brushless DC motor depends on the electronic speed controller (ESC). Some ESCs may be designed to work with variable input voltage and some not.